# Extraction value from nested directories

Tags: python, directory, nested, extract

d_3 = {'key1':'-', 'key2':{'nested_key1':'o', 'nested_key2':'x'}, 'key3':'o'}

How to extract 'x'?

Syntax for getting the value.

Comment: Do you know how to access a dictionary at all? How would you get the value of 'key2'?

Comment: I tried countless combinations. The problem is when I get to the value part. It doesn't recognize it and I dont know which syntax to apply.

Comment: for example   list(l_3['key2'][1]['nested_key'.value])

Comment: What happens if you try just `d_3['key2']`?  How would you get the "value part" of what that returns?

Comment: It returnes both pairs from nested directory, but I need only value for the second.

Comment: In one-liner if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's the same operation as getting a dictionary value, except that you need to do it twice.
`d_3['key2']` gives you the value of key2, in other words that's your nested dictionary.
So `d_3['key2']['nested_key2']` simply gives you the value of your nested_key2.

Have a nice day ;)